# Can't Animate or Transition SwiftUI Images in Sequence

Tags: xcode, animation, swiftui

I have an app with a view where I show images taken with the device's camera (stored
with Core Data) and I want to create the effect of time lapse - say you take photos
of a flower over a period of time and want to show those images in a stream. I have
been able to do that - but I want to have some transition effects between the images
and have not been able to do so. I can apply rotation and a static scale but cannot
fade from 0 to 1 opacity, nor scale up from zero to full frame. I must be missing
something really simple. Here's the code using an array of photos instead of Core Data
for simplicity.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeImageIndex = 0
    @State private var startTimer = false
    @State private var myAnimationBool = true

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
    let myShots = ["CoolEquipment", "FishAndChipsMedium", "FlatheadLake1", "GlacierBusMedium", "Hike", "HuckALaHuckMedium", "JohnAndRiverMedium", "MacDonaldLodgeLakesideMedium"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Text("Sequence")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 25))

                Image(self.myShots[self.activeImageIndex])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width - 20, height: geo.size.width - 20, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)

                    //None of these do anything
                    //.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                    //.animation(.easeInOut)
                    //.transition(.opacity)
                    //.transition(self.myAnimationBool ? .opacity : .slide)
                    //.transition(.scale)
                    //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide))

                    //this works but is static
                    //.scaleEffect(self.myAnimationBool ? 0.5 : 1.0)

                    //this works but again is static
                    //.rotationEffect(.degrees(self.myAnimationBool ? 90 : 0))

                    .onReceive(self.timer) { t in
                        print("in fixed timer")
                        if self.startTimer {
                            self.activeImageIndex = (self.activeImageIndex + 1) % self.myShots.count
                        }
                    }

                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.startTimer.toggle()
                        }) {
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                                Text(self.startTimer ? "Stop" : "Start").font(.headline)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
            }//top VStack
        }.onDisappear{ self.startTimer = false }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 11.3 (11C29)